# which library to call python script from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, angular-fullstack

I am using angular fullstack , a yoeman generator to create a web application. I want to  call python scripts from nodejs and these scripts will be giving back some output which will be displayed in html pages. what library should i use? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) would be what you want. There's a full documentation in the link I've sent you, it's pretty straight forward.

What you might need to know as a minimum is this:

```
child_process = require('child_process');
var script = child_process.exec('python script.js',function(err,stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Output: " + stdout);
});;
```